# How to create a command that outputs the next line of a file in Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a discord server where we give away steam keys as giveaway prizes often.  Currently, I manually cut/paste keys over from a text file but I want a bot command that can automate that.  (they are line seaperated on a TXT file...the bot doesn't have to read txt files, but it needs to be something where I can easily copy/paste into it, as I will be transferring 100+ keys into the bot each time)

I already tried creating a command but it is just giving me error mesages, so I don't know if its better to re-code it or fix my existing code.

Here is my current bot code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const yml = require("../yml.js");
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    if(!message.member.roles.has(message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name == "Faulty Admins").id)) return message.channel.send('Invalid permissions.');
    let file = fs.readFileSync('codes.txt').toString();
    let lines = file.split('\n');
    message.channel.send(lines[0]);
    lines.splice(0, 1);
    fs.writeFile('./codes.txt', lines.join('\n'), function(err) { if(err) console.log(err) });
}
module.exports.help = { name: 'code' }
```

And this is the error I get:

```js
ReferenceError: file is not defined
at Object.module.exports.run (/home/container/commands/code.js:7:17)
at /home/container/index.js:312:33
at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:53:3)
```

I have a codes.txt file in the root of the container with line-separated keys.  I won't be providing that for hopefully obvious reasons. ;)

I need it to be able to output a new key every time, without sending a bunch or errors.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has since been fixed.  I changed the variable name for files, which solved the issue.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const yml = require("../yml.js");
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    if(!message.member.roles.has(message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name == "Faulty Admins").id)) return message.channel.send('Invalid permissions.');
    let steamkeys = fs.readFileSync('codes.txt').toString();
    let lines = steamkeys.split('\n');
    message.channel.send(lines[0]);
    lines.splice(0, 1);
    fs.writeFile('./codes.txt', lines.join('\n'), function(err) { if(err) console.log(err) });
}
module.exports.help = { name: 'code' }
```

Comment: I had to do a bit more modification to get it working with the config file, but otherwise it works fine!